# Avastar behaviour for a scripted weights setting

Tags: scripting, rigging, export

This is a second life question. 
I made a script which defines bones weights.
When i am binding the mesh to avastar and playing with the sliders (here breasts), i am obtaining that result : [image]

As you can see, the rig (arm, leg) is ok... but the breast goes as 90° turned (shifted to the right).

But.. when i upload the same mesh to sl, all is ok : [image]

What can give this result ?

Comment: Drunk surgeon? axis different in SL? hard to say. SL aware readers will need the [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) i guess.

Comment: The particular thing is that weights are set by a script i made. And for now i dont want to distribute it because it is not documented and i need time for that (i will release it in GPL licence). But for now i cant do this documentation. The main point is : how is it possible that a mesh is ok in sl and is not ok for avastar ?